# Matrix factorization for recommendations vs Collaborative filtering

Tags: recommender-system

Some texts seem to list **matrix factorization** as a method for **collaborative filtering**, and more specifically categorize them as a "**model-based approach"** (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_factorization_(recommender_systems)) and [here](https://realpython.com/build-recommendation-engine-collaborative-filtering/)), while others seem to treat them differently (e.g. see [here](https://youtu.be/1JRrCEgiyHM?t=994) where the presenter discusses three **distinct** solutions, content-based, collaborative, *and* **latent-factor-based**. Similar implied distinctions are made[here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mgormley/courses/10601-s17/slides/lecture25-mf.pdf) or e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering))

This is perhaps a matter of semantics and etymology, but what are the merits for each argument? That is, from what perspective is MF a CF method ("model-based or not) or vice-versa?

Comment: What “arguments” you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks @Tim I don't actually know if there are mathematical arguments or interpretations of MF that would group MF as a model-based CF method. If there are none (perhaps because the term CF never had a sufficiently rigorous definition), the explanation may be historical context. So by "argument" here I mean what arguments would an author use to group MF under CF or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix factorization is a kind of [*collaborative filtering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering),

> collaborative filtering is a method of making automatic predictions
>   (filtering) about the interests of a user by collecting preferences or
>   taste information from many users (collaborating).

Matrix factorization is based on a *model* (it learns representation of the data *vs* just finding similar users using some kind of distance metric) that factorizes the matrix of user-item preferences $R$ into two *latent* (unobstructed) variable matrices $P$ and $Q$:

$$ R \approx PQ $$

So *all* the descriptions are correct, they are just of different granularity.

Comment: +1 - Thanks, although I'm not sure I would go as far as to say that _all_ the descriptions are correct, since some of the sources above seem to list user-item matrix factorization approaches as a standalone entity outside of CF. It could be an oversight of the authors, or an unintended interpretation of their text / presentation.

Comment: @Josh I didn’t watch the YouTube video, but the rest of the sources seem to be inline with what I wrote.